# How does this scenario of UNION deduping work in SQL?

Tags: sql, union

UNION removes duplicate whereas UNION ALL doesn't.
But I'm trying to confirm the exact outcome if I UNION these two:

```
select 'aaa' as name, 'existing' as type
UNION 
select 'aaa' as name, 'new' as type
```

and I was hoping that I could trust that it would just give me
'aaa', 'existing'
as the output

Comment: There is no duplicate in your example, so UNION can't remove any. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=695cccd77693fec0631e86838c422b48

Comment: In your hypothetical version, how does the system know which columns the user is thinking are part of the duplicate checks vs the ones that are not checked? Also, in general, there's no ordering in sets of rows, so there would be no reason to expect that *the* row that is output wouldn't be the `new` one.

Comment: You can just run the code and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Union removes duplicate of all column combination. it wont remove duplicate using single column. so the result of the query is 2 row.

Comment: thank you. Sounds like my question was clear then. That was the answer I was after.